# Writing to TextBox via INotifyPropertyChanged not working

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm having an issue with a property invoking a  INotifyPropertyChanged event. I've created a simple concept WPF program that attempts to write to a textbox via a button which calls a function that updates a property (ViewModel1StringProperty). The property is bound  to the textbox and the property invokes a  INotifyPropertyChanged event. I've added this text property to the textbox:

```
Text="{Binding ViewModel1StringProperty, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
```

However, the textbox is still not updated when the button is clicked. One thing to note is the button calls an ICommand which then ultimately updates the property through a function call (TestFunction1). I believe this command is bound correctly to the button but I'm not sure.

Any insight into this issue would be greatly appreciated.

ViewModel Code:

```
    namespace WpfApplicationOnPropertyChanged.ViewModel
    {
        class ViewModel1 : INotifyPropertyChanged
        {
            #region Fields
            string _viewModel1StringProperty;
            public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
            #endregion

        protected void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new  PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }

        #region Properties
        public string ViewModel1StringProperty
        {
            get
            {
                return _viewModel1StringProperty;
            }

            set
            {
                _viewModel1StringProperty = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("ViewModel1StringProperty");
            }
        }
        #endregion

        #region Commands
        public ICommand ViewModelICommandField1
        {
            get
            {
                return new ViewModelICommand(TestFunction1);
            }
        }
        #endregion

        #region Functions

        private void TestFunction1()
        {
            ViewModel1StringProperty = "Test1\n";
        }
        #endregion
    }
}
```

View Code:

```
    namespace WpfApplicationOnPropertyChanged.View
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Interaction logic for View1.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class View1 : UserControl
    {
        #region Fields
        ViewModel1 _viewModel1 = new ViewModel1();
        #endregion

        public View1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.DataContext = _viewModel1;
        }
    }
}
```

XAML Code:

```
    <UserControl x:Class="WpfApplicationOnPropertyChanged.View.View1"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml   /presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplicationOnPropertyChanged.View"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <Grid>
        <TextBox Name="textBox1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="89" Margin="58,62,0,0" Text="{Binding ViewModel1StringProperty, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="181"/>
        <Button Content="Button1"  Command="{Binding ViewModel1ICommandField1}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="106,205,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

ICommand Code:

```
    namespace WpfApplicationOnPropertyChanged.ViewModel
    {
        class ViewModelICommand : ICommand
        {
           private Action _action;

        public ViewModelICommand(Action action)
        {
            _action = action;
        }    

        public void Execute(object parameter)
        {
            _action();
        }

        public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
        {
            return true;
        }

        public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
        {
            add { }
            remove { }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you could accept my answer if it was helpful to you :)

Answer (score 3):

In the XAML you have bound the command of button to `ViewModel1ICommandField1`, but in the View Model its name is `ViewModelICommandField1`.

Please rename either so that they match, and you'll get correct behavior.